# Workflow Running on Item that was copied to library from another workflow?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, copy-item

So I have the following.

Two libraries. **Library A** and **Library B.** I have **Workflow 1** that moves a document from **Library A** to **Library B** when a certain condition is met. I then have **Workflow 2** that is on **Library B** that is set to run on item creation or change.

Problem is **Workflow 2** is not running on items that are added to the library via **Workflow 1**.

I have confirmed it works on Items that are added to the library directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are several possibilities for your issue, outlined in this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/724d1347-c1ab-4dce-96b4-a97a0a320b8b/list-item-created-through-workflow-does-not-start-new-item-workflow?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy

- be cogniscant of using 'Set' versus 'Update' actions. Set will not trigger the Change event, whereas Update will
- insert an event to log to history before any relevant actions were taken.  I set it to log "Start workflow" as the first action
- creating the new list item from with-in a 'Impersonation Step' - once i changed to a normal 'Step' it solved my issues of the second workflow not starting. This fixes it as the new item is no longer being created by a system account.
- adding a 1 minute delay to workflow b may fix it

Good luck!